# Sorting array object in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-2, associative-array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 70
            [percentage] => 66.666666666667
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 72
            [percentage] => 44.444444444444
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 74
            [percentage] => 11.111111111111
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 82
            [percentage] => 60
        )

)
```

How to sort this array based on percentage in descending order i tried with this code but it is not working

```
usort($post_result, array($this, "myfunction"));  
function  myfunction($a, $b)
{
return strcmp($a->percentage, $b->percentage);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123 it does , but i need `descending`

Comment: Read the php manual for `usort()` and you will figure it out how to change it that it works for you :D If not show us your attempts and where you are stuck and what you don't understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
usort($post_result, function($a, $b) {
    if($a['percentage']==$b['percentage']) return 0;
    return $a['percentage'] < $b['percentage']?1:-1;
});
```